# woocommerce how to get $cart_item_key for a single product

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

I'm implementing a Remove Item button next to the add to cart button however I have a problem getting the variable $cart_item_key for a single product. I have the global variables $woocommerce and $product but the only way  $cart_item_key  is used is a foreach which doesn't  help me at all as I need my code to be added in add-to-cart.php.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to set the remove link for each product within loop like this,

```
foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

 echo $cart_item_key;
 if($cart_item['product_id'] == $your_product_id_to_remove ){
    //remove single product
 }
}
```

In any situation you have cart item listing; from that you have to remove, so `foreach` will work with your requirement.

Hope its helps..

Comment: This seems like a very inefficient way to achieve this. I'm aware that the structure of WooCommerce more or less forces this type of solution - however, we're essentially saying:

"For each item in the cart, check it against all of the other items in the cart, if it's a match - do something".

Doing basic maths we can see clearly that we have to iterate through our cart items `Y squared` times (where Y is the number of items in our cart).

1 item - 2 iterations
2 items - 4 iterations
3 items - 9 iterations
4 items - 16 iterations

Answer (score 2):

This code worked for me. Thanks to Jobin Jose (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1258004/jobin-jose) for the solution!

```
foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    if ($cart_item['product_id'] == $product->id ) {
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf('<a href="%s" class="remove" title="%s">&times;</a>', esc_url( $woocommerce->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key) ), __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ) ), $cart_item_key );
}
```